# Get the previous element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select my previous .item

I have this:

```
<div id="um" class="item">um</div>
<div id="dois" class="item">dois</div>
<div id="tres" class="item active">tres</div>
<div id="quatro" class="item">quatro</div>
<div id="cinco" class="item">cinco</div>

<button id="prev>previous</button>
```

and i'm trying with this:

```
 $("#prev").click(function(){
  $(".active").addClass("after").removeClass("active");
  $(".after").prev(".item").addClass("active");
  $(".after").removeClass("after");
  });
```

i'm failing to retrieve the previous .item

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Works fine for me once you fix the missing quote on the previous button's ID: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dM5hq/

Comment: You code is buggy, but kinda works: http://jsfiddle.net/u8ayg/ (Just note the id does not have closing `"`)

Comment: @karthikr Haha, can't believe we wrote EXACTLY the same fiddle within a few seconds. Even the same debugging color. :)

Comment: Two upvotes? For a missing quote? Seriously?

Comment: For me, still not working: http://codepen.io/vbavinicius/pen/zrJBw

Answer (score 3):

Works fine, you need to close quote on the button id attribute.

```
<button id="prev">previous</button>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4YLjg/

---

UPDATE

According to the link from the comment, your `prev` click listener is defined within your `next` click listener, so each time you click the next button, it generates a new `prev` listener which results in `prev` getting triggered one additional time for every time you clicked the next button...

See the working version here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cGrvq

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to overload JS using another class. Have you tried this :

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
  var prev = $(".active").prev();
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  prev.addClass("active");
});
```

There's a good example like what you wanna do on the jQuery official prev() page : http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Heelo Pete, thanks for the help, but can you answer me something?

Comment: In line 3, you are removing .active class, how jquery will find .active class in line 4, if you removed right above?

Comment: You're telling that your codepen.io is not working, but it does work !

Answer (score 0):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5RGJ4/)

- You need to separate both the click handlers. The click of previous was inside the handler of net before.
- Also, you need to handle the event where there is no previous element. For `um` press previous.

---

Next :

```
$("#next").click(function () {

    // SETANDO A CONTAGEM DE ITENS
    var len = $(".active.item").next(".item").length;

    // ADICIONANDO O PRÓXIMO ITEM
    $(".active").addClass("before").removeClass("active");
    $(".before").next(".item").addClass("active");
    $(".before").removeClass("before");

    // SE FOR O ÚLTIMO ITEM, RETORNE AO PRIMEIRO

    if (len <= 0) {
        $(".active").addClass("before").removeClass("active");
        $(".item").first().addClass("active");
        $(".before").removeClass("before");
    }


});
```

---

Previous :

```
$("#prev").click(function () {
    var len = $(".active.item").prev(".item").length;


    $(".active").addClass("after").removeClass("active");
    $(".after").prev(".item").addClass("active");
    $(".after").removeClass("active").removeClass('after');
    console.log(len);

    if (len <= 0) {
        $(".active").addClass("after").removeClass("active");
        $(".item").last().addClass("active");
        //$(".after").removeClass("before");
    }
});
```